# Remove slashes from geom_line plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have seen several questions related to this, but I gather the solution might be specific to the type of graph being called in ggplot (i.e., geom_bar vs geom_line). I have not been able to find a solution to removing the slashes from a geom_line graph. Also this might be complicated by my specific graph where I want my ribbons with outlines. Here is my simplified code:

```
soil.type<-c('d','w','d','w','d','w','d','w')
date<-c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4)
mean<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
low.cl<-c(.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5)
up.cl<-c(1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5) 
mydata<-data.frame(soil.type, date, mean, low.cl, up.cl)

ggplot(mydata, aes(date, mean, color=soil.type))+
   geom_ribbon(data=mydata, aes(ymin=low.cl, ymax=up.cl, 
   linetype=soil.type), color='black', width=0.5, alpha=0.3)+
   geom_point(aes(shape=soil.type), size=6, color='black')+
   geom_line(aes(linetype=soil.type), color='black', size=2)
```

I have tried:

```
guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(color=NULL)))
```

But this didn't work in my case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to specify that I'm talking about removing the slashes from the legend labels. thanks

Comment: Have you tried `guides(linetype=guide_legend(override.aes=list(linetype=NULL))`?

Comment: That didn't work for me.

Comment: Update to the latest version of `ggplot2`. That behavior was deprecated a while back.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I will do that.